# ¿Cuál es el error en este código?-(Python)

Tags: python, condiciones, comparaciones

Esta es la actividad, Realizar un programa que convierta una nota porcentual del 0 al 100 a una letra entre A y F de acuerdo a la siguiente conversión:

```
A: 90–100
B: 80–89
C: 70–79
D: 60–69
F: 0–59
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ayudaría mucho leas [ask] y nos compartas por ejemplo ¿al ejecutar ese script da algún mensaje de error?

Comment: Al decir `"Su nota porcentual es A"` no queda del todo claro, creo que sería mejor -si no puedes implementar `F-Strings`- algo como `"Su nota porcentual es equivalente a A"`

Comment: Primero va el signo `<` y luego el `=`

Answer (score 2):

Estimado, para la próxima vez que requiera preguntar algo, adjunte el error. Aquí veo 3 errores:

1. En su input usted espera que ingrese números enteros, por eso debe indicar *int* antes del input:
   `int(input("Ingrese su nota porcentual"))`
2. En los condicionales, el `<`,  `>`  van antes del `=` y no después:

```
if numero >= 1   #CORRECTO
if numero =>1    #INCORRECTO
```

3. Para hacer más de una comparación en un `if` usando `and` debe especificar cual variable está siendo validada:

**Correcto**

```
elif notaPorcentual <= 0 **and notaPorcentual** <= 59:
     print("Su nota porcentual es F")
```

**Incorrecto**

```
elif notaPorcentual => 0 and <= 59:  and <=59: ...
```

Estos errores están en todas las lineas de codigo, aquí dejo el codigo corregido, saludos.

```
notaPorcentual = int(input("Ingrese su nota porcentual")) #Debe ser INT antes de input si ingresará números enteros.
if notaPorcentual >= 90 and notaPorcentual <= 100:   #Siempre va el < / > antes del =
    print("Su nota porcentual es A")
elif notaPorcentual <= 80 and notaPorcentual <= 89:
    print("Su nota porcentual es B")
elif notaPorcentual <= 70 and notaPorcentual <= 79:
    print("Su nota porcentual es C")
elif notaPorcentual <= 60 and notaPorcentual <= 69:
    print("Su nota porcentual es D")
elif notaPorcentual <= 50 and notaPorcentual <= 59:
    print("Su nota porcentual es E")
elif notaPorcentual <= 0 and notaPorcentual <= 59:
    print("Su nota porcentual es F")
```

Comment: Buena respuesta, solo te falto decirle que el código va como texto y no como imagen :)

Comment: Buen punto @Raravar con la notación de las desigualdades... también se podría añadir que `Python` puede verificar si un valor cae dentro de un rango con `90 <= nota_porcentual <= 100`.

Comment: @Raravar Al realizar las correcciones que me sugeriste me surge el error mostrado arriba. Cómo podría solucionar eso?

Comment: @Lucho Sanchez te sigue dando `invalid syntax`?

Comment: Si, me marca como error sobre todo la linea del if, fijate arriba actualicé como está ahora el código.

Comment: @LuchoSanchez, Estimado, al final de mi post añadí la corrección a su codigo, donde dice :  "Estos errores están en todas las lineas de codigo, aquí dejo el codigo corregido, saludos."

Answer (score 1):

La conversión se puede hacer en una sola línea de código:

```
nota_porcentual = int(input("Ingrese su nota"))
nota = "FFFFFFDCBAA"[nota_porcentual // 10]
print(nota)
```

Funciona así: la nota porcentual se divide por 10, lo que nos da un valor entre 0 y 10. Ese valor lo usamos de índice en un arreglo de once posiciones ("FFFFFFDCBAA"), que tiene en la posición cero la letra para notas entre 0 y 9, en la posición 1 la letra para notas desde 10 hasta 19, etc.

Comment: Esta respuesta es muy elegante @CandidMoe... se tienen que emplear un `A` adicional al final porque el último carácter corresponde a la nota `top` 100, sin eso tiraría error para ese caso puntual... por lo demás, bien empleado el concepto de aritmética modular.

Answer (score 0):

ya te han corregído el código asi que sólo debo acotar que no olvídes cerrar con un (else) en caso de que por error se ingresen números fuera de los condicionales establecídos. así queda más prolíjo el código y completo.

```
A = 90-100
B = 80-89
C = 70-79
D = 60-69
F = 0-59

notaPorcentual = int (input ("ingrese su nota porcentual"))

if notaPorcentual >=90 and notaPorcentual <=100 :
    print ("su nota porcentual es A")
elif notaPorcentual >=80 and notaPorcentual <=89 :
    print ("su nota porcentual es B")
elif notaPorcentual >=70 and notaPorcentual <=79 :
    print ("su nota porcentual es C")
elif notaPorcentual >=60 and notaPorcentual <=69 :
    print ("su nota porcentual es D")
elif notaPorcentual >=0 and notaPorcentual <=59 :
    print ("su nota porcentual es F")

else :                                  # para el caso de que por error se tipee por ejemplo un -10 o un 150 y el programa pueda responder al usuario para que éste sepa qué corregír
    print ("ingrese una nota porcentual válida")
```